# Passing array to an API

Tags: php

i am trying to pass an array to an API, the API takes array in following format when i run it in `POSTMAN (raw form)`,

```
{
"records": [
    {
    "content": "50.150.50.55",
    "type": "A",
    "name": "test.mauqe.com",
    "prio": null,
    "ttl": 3600
    }
    ]
}
```

while am trying to pass the array in my code in this format,

```
 $data = array(
             "content" => "50.150.50.55",
             "type" => "A",
             "name" => "gulpanra.mauqe.com",
             "prio" => "null",
             "ttl" => "3600"
             );
```

i don't understand, whats the problem. response said error **`(Data sending format error)`**. plz help

Comment: Please post a more complete code example, which shows how you are calling the functions that you are using to send this data from php to this API service.

Comment: are you forgetting to add records? and have you tried 3600 as a number instead of a string? and then tried null as a null instead of a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = array('records' => array());
$data['records'][] = array( 

                "content" => "50.150.50.55",
                "type" => "A",
                "name" => "gulpanra.mauqe.com",
                "prio" => null,
                "ttl" => 3600

        );

$json_output = json_encode( $data );
echo $json_output;
?>
```

This will give the following as output:

```
{"records":[{"content":"50.150.50.55","type":"A","name":"gulpanra.mauqe.com","prio":null,"ttl":3600}]}
```

Comment: you are the genius (Y)

Answer (score 2):

The API expects an array of maps. The following is an array of maps.

```
[
    {
    "content": "50.150.50.55",
    "type": "A",
    "name": "test.mauqe.com",
    "prio": null,
    "ttl": 3600
    },
    {},
    {},
    ...
]
```

What you are passing is not the same. You're passing in a single map

```
{
         "content" => "50.150.50.55",
         "type" => "A",
         "name" => "gulpanra.mauqe.com",
         "prio" => "null",
         "ttl" => "3600"
 }
```

Try amending $data to:

```
$data = array();

array_push($data['records'], array(
         "content" => "50.150.50.55",
         "type" => "A",
         "name" => "gulpanra.mauqe.com",
         "prio" => "null",
         "ttl" => "3600"
));
```

Comment: This is most likely the correct one, but it also needs it as `json` ;-)

Comment: exactly ..........you are right,i have already convert into json,  but how to convert my array into array of maps. pleaseeee

Comment: I assume that the json_encode is already sorted, as in the OP already had it. See the final part of the solution, where I have suggested how to declare $data.

Comment: i have already tried, but the same error...........you understand my question, but try to give me the corract solution plz

Answer (score 1):

Use `json_encode` to convert your array in json format and then pass it to the api.

The Api you are using is expecting data in json format.

```
$data = json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert array into json format in order to pass it to the api. use `json_encode()`. Use the code below

```
$array = array( "content" => "50.150.50.55", "type" => "A", "name" => "gulpanra.mauqe.com", "prio" => "null", "ttl" => "3600" );
$data = json_encode($data); // Pass this to API
```

Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

you have to make array outside for example

you are using this type of array to encode

```
$data['records'] = array(
       'content' => '50.150.50.55',
       and so on
);
```

change this array to this

```
$data = array(
  'content' => '50.150.50.55',
   and so on
);
```

this will help